# file does not update until restarting in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, save

Good morning/afternoon to all, I've struggling with this for a while, any help would be appreciated:

I have a struct in C, and a binary file where I save the data as an "array", so they are stored one next to the other, let's say I have three "instances" of the struct, they are saved like this [0][1][2] in the file.

The problem is when I delete a register, for instance the position 2 equals [1], in the file is correctly handled and the file look like this [0][2].

but if I `read_register` with position 2 in the console, it will keep showing the information that was before, I mean information of [1].

So I have to finish the program, and when I start again, It shows correctly the information of [2].

I will add source:

```
void delete_register(){

    printf("- - Borrar registro - -\nHay %i registros, ingrese el numero que desea borrar:\n", size);
    int pos;
    scanf(" %i", &pos);
    pos--;

    FILE * file= fopen("dataDogs.dat", "rb+");
    if (file == NULL) {
         printf("Hubo un error leyendo el archivo.\n");
    }

    size--;
    // poisition the pointer of file in the position to erase
    fseek(file, sizeof(struct dog_type)*pos, SEEK_SET);

    //start overwriting the data with the information of the next in the "array"
    while(pos < size){
        fwrite(load_pointer(++pos), sizeof(struct dog_type), 1, file);
    }

    // deletes last "sizeof(struct dog_type)" bytes, to free the space of the one that was deleted
    truncate("dataDogs.dat", sizeof(struct dog_type)*size);
    fclose(file);
}


void * load_pointer(int pos){
    struct dog_Type *dog_pt = malloc(sizeof(struct dog_type));
    FILE * file= fopen("dataDogs.dat", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
         printf("Hubo un error leyendo el archivo.\n");
    }

    // position pointer of file
    fseek(file, sizeof(struct dog_type)*pos, SEEK_SET);

    //read the first sizeof(struct dog_type) bytes
    fread(dog_pt, sizeof(struct dog_type), 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    return dog_pt;
}

void read_register() {
    printf("- - Leer registro - -\nHay %i registros, ingrese el numero que desea ver:\n", size);
    int pos;
    scanf(" %i", &pos);
    print(load_pointer(--pos));
}
```

Comment: Put in fflush() before the close to ensure that the operations have completed.

Comment: @Jumper Why did you tag this as `C++` when this is clearly `C`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie C and C++ are similar and share many things, maybe they share this same issue, so more people could help me

Comment: `fclose` implies flushing the stream. The `truncate` call (I assume POSIX `truncate`) shouldn't happen as long as the file is open. (Even better, use `ftruncate`.)

Comment: @Jumper The code is C, not C++.  If you want proof, this fails to compile for C++:  `struct dog_Type *dog_pt = malloc(sizeof(struct dog_type));`  If you want help with C++, someone could suggest you rewrite the whole thing using `std::vector` instead of `malloc`.  Do you want that advice?